# How to scatter all points at identical locations in CartoDB?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I am working on a project in which data points are often at the same location (e.g. Rome). This poses a problem because the data points then overlap and cannot be clicked on.

I found some SQL at http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8695515 that scattered the points very well when I applied it to one location. However, my final dataset could have dozens of identical locations, and I don't want to enter the same SQL dozens of times for each identical location.

Is there a way to modify this SQL (or something similar) so that it scatters all points at the same location (i.e. it identifies the locations at which there are multiple data points, and then scatters the points at each of those locations)?